# When do I need to use an architectural design pattern?

Tags: android, design-patterns

I'm working on an app for Android and I'm confused when do I need to use architectural design pattern.

My project is medium size and I'm working on it alone, but I want to learn how to work using a design pattern, because most of the companies use it when building a project.

How does one select an architectural design pattern when there are so many of them?

Answer (score 3):

You have to read and decide. Check these from Google:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture